# How to send an event to the object a control is bound to?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Instead of creating a Handler for a click event on a xaml control, I want the handler to be implemented into the Class of the object that control is bound to. If it's possible.

I am making Game of Life in WPF, I have a Cell class, one of its properties is Color, which is modified when another property, State, is changed. State can be either Dead or Alive. In the MainWindow.xaml.cs I instantiate an ObservableCollection of Cells. In the MainWindow.xaml I have a UniformGrid that is bound to the ObservableCollection of Cells and when a Cell changes its state a Cell in the UniformGrid changes its color. 
What I want to do is to make a handler for the Click event on a DataGridCell, and that handler should be implemented in the Cell class, that way the Cell that is bound to the clicked DataGridCell will trigger it's own handler.

the Cell class:

```cs
    public class Cell : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName){/*...*/}

        public void ChangeState(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e){/*...*/}

        private CellState state;
        public CellState State{/*...*/}
        private CellState nextState;
        public Color Color{/*...*/}

        /* Other irrelevant stuff */
    }
```

I keep getting the MainWindow does not contain definition for 'ChangeState' and I'd like to bypass it somehow, since I want the handler to be inside the Cell class itself.

the MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```cs
    public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var vm = new ViewModel();

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                vm.Cells.Add(new Cell());

            DataContext = vm;
        }
```

the MainWindow.xaml:

```xml
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Cells}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Columns="10"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DataGridCell BorderThickness="0.1" MouseUp="ChangeState">
                    <DataGridCell.Background>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Color}"/>
                    </DataGridCell.Background>
                </DataGridCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Instead of a `DataGridCell`  you could use a `ToggleButton` or a  custom Control that implements [`ICommandSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.icommandsource?view=netframework-4.7.2) and invokes an `ICommand` that is implemented in your `Cell`. Find more about commands [Commanding Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/commanding-overview)

Comment: The `ToggleButton`already comes with two states and you can change its appearance by overriding the `ControlTemplate`. But the basic idea is to use commands.

Comment: Sounds fairly simple, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to read more about [mvvm](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mvvm/) pattern and ICommand interface.
Then you can use ToggleButton

```
<ToggleButton Command="{Binding MyCommand}"/>
```

And in vm:

```
public ICommand MyCommand => new RelayCommand(() => /* your method, for example cell adding */);
```

Comment: It seems commands are the only way, I heard of them but I thought there would be a more straightforward way. Can't complain tho.